# How to save games on different memory slots

Tags: pc, fable-3

My brother and I want to play Fable 3. The problem is that we can't save the game on different memory slots as there is no option to save.

I started the first game. When my brother started playing the game, my save levels were lost.

So, is there any way I can start a new game without affecting his save levels?

Let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: Are you playing on PC or 360?

Comment: I'm playing on PC, sorry I forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fable 3 stores your saves in `C:\Users\(Username)\Saved Games\Lionhead Studios\Fable 3`, so the simplest solution is for you and your brother to use separate Windows accounts (which is something you should probably be doing anyway).

Altenratively, you can use individual scripts (.bat or other) to move the saves around before launching the game for you so you can maintain 2 separate sets of saves on the same user account.